# jquery mobile vmouse up event handler fired twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using vmouseup event handler for all the interactive button elements in my
jQuery mobile + Phonegap application.

For example, Check the following code.

```
$('#sBtn').live('vmouseup', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  alert("Inside Function");
})
```

Here, What happens is, the event has fired twice **(got two 'Inside Function' alerts)** in android based touch screen mobiles. 
How to prevent this? or what is the best approach to avoid this?

NOTE: I tried event.preventDefault() and event.stopImmediateProbagtion(), but even i faced the same problem. Can anyone please brief what happens behind and how to disable the button after clicking that.

I tried `$('#sBtn').off('vmouseup').on( 'vmouseup', function (event) {})` also, but no luck. can anyone suggest/advcie what shall I do to prevent this...?

Comment: `.off('vmouseup').on('vmouseup')` try this.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think the problem is that you are using `live()`

From jquery stopImmediatePropagation.

> Additional Notes:
>
> Since the **.live() method handles events once they have propagated** to
>   the top of the document, **it is not possible to stop propagation** of
>   live events. Similarly, events handled by .delegate() will propagate
>   to the elements to which they are delegated; event handlers bound on
>   any elements below it in the DOM tree will already have been executed
>   by the time the delegated event handler is called. These handlers,
>   therefore, may prevent the delegated handler from triggering by
>   calling event.stopPropagation() or returning false.

Try changing it to something else (`bind` or `on`), it seems you cannot stop propagation as is.